# Swift: Does DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async lock the main thread?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am currently trying to resolve an `0x8BADF00D`.

`faultingThread` is 0 which I suppose to be the main thread. However, I don't think the bulk work that I am doing actually goes down in the main thread.

In a function that does run on the main thread I do

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
 // ... heavy work

 // and after the work is done I do
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1.0) {
    // ... displaying heavy work
  }
}
```

Is there an obvious fault in my logic? I thought the .userInitiated would leave the main thread, especially on `.async`.

"exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGKILL"},
"termination" : {"flags":6,"code":2343432205,"namespace":"FRONTBOARD","reasons":["<RBSTerminateContext| domain:10 code:0x8BADF00D explanation:scene-update watchdog transgression: application<com.test>:579 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 10.00 seconds","ProcessVisibility: Background","ProcessState: Running","WatchdogEvent: scene-update","WatchdogVisibility: Background","WatchdogCPUStatistics: (",""Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 21.740 (user 21.740, system 0.000), 99% CPU",",""Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 9.832, 45% CPU"",") reportType:CrashLog maxTerminationResistance:Interactive>"]},
"faultingThread" : 0,

Comment: I believe you should do heavy work on `.background`. User initiated is for other kind of work "The quality-of-service class for tasks that prevent the user from actively using your app."

Comment: You are right and I understand but I thought .userInitiated would be okay compared to userInteractive, the latter of which surely blocks the thread. I will try with .utility now and let you know. I really has to be executed as fast as possible.

Comment: You're doing `async` dispatch which doesn't block the thread at the moment it is called, whether that's the main thread or another one.
What I don't understand is why do you use the `asyncAfter` instead of a simple `async` on the main queue to display the work. Even better you could use a DispatchGroup to notify when the work in the background is done and has to be delivered to the main queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern here is correct (though a more reasonable QoS would be well advised). Your watchdog problem, where the main thread was blocked, rests elsewhere. But dispatching expensive process to a background queue, and then dispatching UI/model updates back to the main queue, is the correct procedure.

---

A word of caution: This general pattern *can* block the main thread in certain scenarios. Specifically, if you had thread explosion (e.g., more than 64 tasks dispatched to that global queue), one can block/deadlock. GCD has a very limited thread pool (64 at this point) and if you exceed this, subsequent attempts to dispatch to that queue will block until the queue is freed up. This generally is only a problem where you are using locks, semaphores, or otherwise waiting. Unfortunately, there is not enough in your code snippet for us to diagnose the problem in this particular case.

So, if you have a thread explosion, you should refactor to constrain the maximum degree of concurrency. Operation queues have `maxConcurrentOperation` to facilitate that. GCD has `concurrentPerform` which will not exceed the maximum number of threads permitted to run at any given time. The Swift 5.5 cooperative thread pool also constrains parallelism to a reasonable limit. Combine has “max publishers” for controlling the degree of concurrency. In past, we might have used non-zero semaphores to constrain the degree of concurrency (though nowadays we would tend to use one of the aforementioned contemporary solutions). There are lots of approaches that mitigate thread explosion.

All of this assumes that the problem rests with thread explosion (which is the likely culprit if the nested `async` dispatches are blocking). If you do not have thread explosion, then you simply have something else, completely unrelated, blocking the main thread.

Comment: That is an exceptional answer. I actually put 80% of my project on a background queue now since the crash log is unable to tell from where exactly the problem stems now - and so far it's been fine. But you have no idea how valuable that information you have given me is to me for future reference, I really appreciate you taking the time and 64 indeed sounds very limited, I'm sure I could've easily hit that in the past without knowing. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

QoS determines the priority at which the system schedules tasks for execution only.

You can always check a current thread with `Thread.current`:

```swift
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    print(Thread.current.description)
}
```

Outputs:

```
<NSThread: 0x6000005bde00>{number = 7, name = (null)}`
```

The main thread has `number = 0` and `name = main` only so your code runs on a background thread and you can do heavy work on it.